# Talk myself out of pursuing my dream

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

I have just read an article from a life coach. And it says:

(Excerpt)

> ...I've identified 5 themes that cause us to **talk ourselves out of** pursuing our dreams.

Mine is:

> to **talk myself out of** pursuing my dream.

Is my sentence still correct?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: totally correct

Comment: you also have to change 'us' to 'me'

Comment: I think the specific example context is a slightly odd cause/effect reversal. I'd expect *5 themes **that we use** to talk ourselves out of pursuing our dreams*. It's not those themes that make us do something - we use them to help us do something we already intended to do anyway.

Comment: @Fumble, I got confused a lil' bit about your comment, coz you didn't quote it. 'I'd expect 5 themes that we use to talk ourselves out of pursuing our dreams''-from what you have written. Whereas, ''...I've identified 5 themes that cause us to talk ourselves out of pursuing our dreams''--- this is taken from a lifecoach's introductory paragraph before she break it down or elaborate several tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.  It fits right into the same theme:

> I recognized that these reasons were simply more ways I used to **talk myself out of** pursuing my lifelong ambition to be a lion tamer -- that I didn't have the right hat, or that I didn't have enough money to buy the lions, or that chartered accountancy was a good, steady occupation for a mild-mannered Englishman.

Reference: [Monty Python / Vocational Guidance Counselor Sketch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bNARNsIHzvQ).  At the end of this short comedy, Mr. Anchovy quickly *talks himself out* of trying banking because "it's a big decision", etc.

Life coaches and other self-help professionals will often use the generic "we" in this situation to include all people in the description.

> **We** often talk **ourselves** out of doing what we truly want with our lives, perhaps because we feel we don't deserve that kind of fulfillment.